# How to write `Semigroup` instance and their `quickCheck`s on parameterized types?

Tags: haskell, semigroup

In the exercises of Haskell Programming from First Principle book on Semigroup, I am asked to write `quickCheck` for user defined typeclasses. There are many typeclasses, but I do not understand how to write even the basic ones:

### Problems:

The first is for `Trivial`:

```
module Exercise where

import Test.QuickCheck

data Trivial =
  Trivial
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Semigroup Trivial where
  _ <> _ = undefined

instance Arbitrary Trivial where
  arbitrary = return Trivial

semigroupAssoc :: (Eq m, Semigroup m) => m -> m -> m -> Bool
semigroupAssoc a b c = (a <> (b <> c)) == ((a <> b) <> c)

type TrivialAssoc = Trivial -> Trivial -> Trivial -> Bool
```

The second is for

```
newtype Identity a = Identity a
```

and the third is for:

```
data Two a b =
  Two a b
```

### My answers:

For the first, I changed the `instance` expression to

```
instance Semigroup Trivial where
  _ <> _ = Trivial
```

and it works.

I tried the following code but not work for the second:

```
newtype Identity a = Identity a

instance (Semigroup a) => Semigroup (Identity a) where
  (Identity a1) <> (Identity a2) = Identity (a1 <> a2)

instance Arbitrary (Identity a) where
  arbitrary = return (Identity a)

type IdentityAssoc =
  (Identity a0) -> (Identity a1) -> (Identity a2) -> Bool

main :: IO ()
main =
  quickCheck (semigroupAssoc :: IdentityAssoc)
```

I find I do not understand what the `quickTest` should check here. I even tried:

```
import Data.NonEmpty

newtype Identity a = Identity a

instance (Semigroup a) => Semigroup (Identity a) where
  (Identity a1) <> (Identity a2) = Identity (a1 <> a2)

instance Arbitrary (Identity a) where
  arbitrary = return (Identity a)

type IdentityAssoc =
  (Identity (NonEmpty Int)) -> (Identity (NonEmpty Int)) -> (Identity (NonEmpty Int)) -> Bool

main :: IO ()
main =
  quickCheck (semigroupAssoc :: IdentityAssoc)
```

to make the parameterized types' parameters concrete. But it does not work either.

For the third, I do not know how to write them. But I think it is similar to the second one.

Can someone explain on these so that I can understand how to write the `instance` of parameterized Semigroups and their `quickTest` arbitrary?

Comment: What do you mean that 'it does not work'? Please edit your question to describe the actual problem(s) you're seeing.

Comment: sorry for confusing you. I am also confused by the intent of these questions. So when I say it works, I really mean that these code compiles. And when I say it does not work, they cannot compile. But I also want to know the intent of these exercise, so I used it does not work. But it is somewhat confusing, too.  Sorry for that.

Comment: These types are not higher-kinded. They are parameterized, but their parameters are types; to be higher-kinded, their parameters would need to themselves be parameterized types. I've fixed your question up for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
instance Arbitrary (Identity a) where
  arbitrary = return (Identity a)
```

`a` is not a value variable, it is a type variable. We need a value of type `a` to pass to the `Identity` constructor, not the `a` type itself.

So we need something like

```
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (Identity a) where
  arbitrary = do
     x <- arbitrary         -- generate a value of type a
     return (Identity x)    -- turn it into a value of type (Identity a)
```

(or, more concisely, `arbitrary = Identity <$> arbitrary`)

Note how we have to require that `a` is a type for which we can generate random samples (adding `Arbitrary a =>` after `Instance`). Otherwise, we can't use `x <- arbitrary` to generate a sample for `a`.

Further:

```
type IdentityAssoc =
  (Identity a0) -> (Identity a1) -> (Identity a2) -> Bool
```

Here we can't refer to `a1,a1,a2`, since we haven't defined those types anywhere. We need to choose concrete types, like `Int`. Further, these three types must be the same type, since `(<>)` takes two values of the same type, and returns a value in that type.

Comment: Hi, @chi. Should the instance of `Semigroup` use `a1`, `a2`? If so, why is it different from the instance of type `IdentityAssoc`? like in this: 
`instance (Semigroup a) => Semigroup (Identity a) where
  (Identity a1) <> (Identity a2) = Identity (a1 <> a2)`

Comment: @cmal No in should be `instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Identity a)`. There is no instance for `IdentityAssoc`, that is a function type for which we do not need a semigroup.